# Get primary key of inserted row after session.execute has run in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a MS SQL table called reports with following structure. I want to get the row_id of the row that was just inserted:

```
r_id int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
report_type int,
report_source varchar,
received_date datetime,
```

I have created an engine and session_scope() for handeling connection. My code looks as follows:

```
with session_scope() as session:
    result_object = session.execute("""INSERT INTO reports (report_type, report_source, received_date) VALUES (3, 'Email', '24-06-2021 12:00')""")
    session.commit()
    for res in result_object:
        print "report id of inserted row is: ", res['r_id']
```

Apart from this I have also tried fetchone() but I am always getting the error as:

> ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

Out of desperation I have also tried adding "RETURNING *" at the end of the query but I get "ProgrammingError: Incorrect syntax near 'RETURNING'. " What are the other reliable ways to get the report id of loaded row.
PS. I do not want to use ORM, I know this can be done easily in ORM by doing session.add(object) then "object.r_id". How do we do it when I am using a query?

Comment: Does nt `result_object.lastrowid` works? I think you have to do it before committing tho.

Comment: No I am getting a different error as "AttributeError: 'pyodbc.Cursor' object has no attribute 'lastrowid'"

Comment: I ll reply in answer to provide an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use OUTPUT then (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15). Assume your id column is `report_id`

```
"""INSERT INTO reports (report_type, report_source, received_date) 
OUTPUT Inserted.report_id 
VALUES (3, 'Email', '24-06-2021 12:00')"""
```

Comment: Yes that's it. It worked perfectly when I did result_object.fetchone(). Thanks a ton @karolos K